# htaccess exception / "deny from all except Paypal"

Tags: .htaccess

I spent my evening on this problem and I did not find how to solve/bypass it :-(

I have in "mydomain.com/admin/" a .htaccess file with the following :

```
<Files ~ "[^index]\.php$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
</Files>
```

The goal of this .htaccess is to protect all the included files, as inc/config.php for example, from being directly called.

My problem is that I wish to make an exception for a notification php file used by paypal.
In other word, I have a file "mydomain.com/admin/paypal/notify.php" and I wish to allow paypal.com to execute it.

I tried tenth of things, as adding a "Files" authorization in the .htaccess

```
<Files /admin/paypal/notify.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from paypal.com
</Files>
```

But succesless :-(

... as if

```
<Files ~ "[^index]\.php$">
```

was the only followed rule.

Comment: Does order the rules are applied matter in Apache?  Meaning, do you need to block all php, then allow the one or visa versa?

Answer (score 2):

**<Files *filename*>** only apply to a filename, you cannot use a path with it.

The [Files directive documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#files) states:

> The directives given within this
>   section will be applied to any object
>   with a basename (last component of
>   filename) matching the specified
>   filename.

**Possible Solution:**

In the directory **admin/paypal**, create an .htaccess with:

```
<Files notify.php>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from All
  Allow from paypal.com
</Files>
```

**Edit:** reversed Deny and Allow.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that doing an allow from paypal.com will require the FQDN of the IP address hitting your site to be precisely paypal.com while looking through my logs, notifications come from notify.paypal.com (last three requests came from 66.211.170.66)  I don't have any in the previous five days, so, I can't confirm whether they all came from the same IP block.

Comment: thank you for your answers !
Unfortunately, I can't make it work :-(
Don't you think that <Files ~ "[^index]\.php$"> blocks the access to /paypal/notify.php ??

But anyway, the fact that I need to use IPs instead of domain name makes me think I must change my strategy and use PHP to make controls : I don't want my notifications blocked because a Paypal IP is unknown by my htaccess :-)

Thank you all... mhammout